# Using google colab and I'm struggling to access my data set

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, arcgis, geopandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uU6O.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4HIT.png)I keep getting the "no such file or directory" response even though the files are indeed there. Does anyone have a solution to this problem/can recommend other ways to read this data set? It is a gbd.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

file = 'drive/My Drive/gis/tormwater-data'
gdf = gpd.read_file(file)

print(gdf.shape)
print(gdf.crs)
gdf.head()
```

I'm wondering if this is complicated because of the data file itself (I've attached a picture of what some of the files looks like in the folder. Anyways I was hoping to load this data set in colab. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX0GL.png)

Comment: The root `path` should look like `'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/'` and if the file name is `'tormwater-data'` then you need to include the file type (e.g. `'.png'`; so like `'tormwater-data.png'`).

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the path.

i tend to avoid colab, but when i do, i have constructed these functions to help with getting data.

for example i put a text file in the `Colab Notebooks` folder (which is where the colab notebooks are). You can make subfolders from here...

You can then use these functions to mount the drive and read the file.

(i just read a text file here).

```py
import os
from google import colab
from google.colab import drive

def mount_drive():
    ''' check if the drive is mounted, if not, then mount it '''
    # Check if drive is mounted
    if not os.path.ismount('/content/gdrive'):
        drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    else:
        print('Drive already mounted')


def file_location(file_name = 'test.txt'):
    ''' given a file, get the full path to file '''

    # this is where the colab files live
    colab_files = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/'
    file_name = 'test.txt'
    file_path_name = os.path.join(colab_files, file_name)
    return  file_path_name


def check_path(file_path_name:str):
    ''' check if the path exists '''
    if os.path.exists(file_path_name):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def get_data(file_path_name:str)->str:
    ''' read the data from a given file '''
    with open(file_path_name, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    return contents
```